# When Creating a WCF service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

I have already a MVC-webapplication, I wounder should I create a new WCF Service Application or should I insert a service in same webapp under the folder "Model"?

What is the best solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the WCF service is exposing models from your MVC project, I would stick it it the same project. If it has logic pertained to code outside the MVC solution, I would create a separate application.

Comment: Hi mike, What do you mean by exposing? All projects, apps that Iam using is inside the Soultion the same solution, I just don't know if I should create a new application or add to the same webbapplication?

Comment: If the WCF service is tied to the data in the MVC application I would keep them together. If it has services for other things, I would create a separate application. It's a matter of separation of concerns and keeping things which belong together in the same place. That's my view at least.